# mysql concat with trim

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I've got a table which holds a bunch of addresses in cells labelled address | city. 
I am attempting to merge the complete address into the common 'address, city' format.

Occasionally, in my database, I will have one of the location cells empty. Therefore, I do a IFNULL in my concat line, but I end up with a leading or trailing ','. 
I have tried the 'trim' function along with my concat, but still get trailing ',' on occasion.

This is how I've written my query

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM CONCAT(IFNULL(address,''), ', ', IFNULL(city,''))) FROM locals
```

Any idea why I would have this behavior? Is there a better way of building my concat statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your query is just missing a space after the comma in the BOTH statement. That seems to work for me

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ', ' FROM CONCAT(IFNULL(address,''), ', ', IFNULL(city,''))) FROM locals;
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, though I'm surprised that the space after the comma would mean to mysql that it wouldn't strip the comma, but in the end it saved me from having an extra space in my line. 
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is quite long but it seems to work.

```
SELECT TRIM(CONCAT(IFNULL(address,''), IF(address IS NOT NULL AND city IS NOT NULL, ', ',''), IFNULL(city,''))) FROM locals
```

So with this data:

```
address          city
----------------------------
High Street   Southampton
NULL          London
Station Road    NULL
London Road   Brighton
```

You get this:

```
High Street, Southampton
London
Station Road
London Road, Brighton
```

Answer (score -1):

stripping successive separators like "a,b,,,,c,d,e,,,,,eed, sffre" seems to be elusive of any elegant solution for GROUP_CONCAT

Methods used are to create views for each condition that avoids consecutive separators and then a union or join of the individual such views.